# Read a file from background task

Tags: c#, background, task, async-await

I'm trying to call a method from inside the Run method of a background task which among other it desirializes a xml file. The problem is that I end up in a deadlock. This is the methos that reads the file

```
protected async Task<Anniversaries> readFile(string fileName)
    {                        
        IStorageFile file;
        Anniversaries tempAnniversaries;   

        file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);            
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream =
            await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))                
        using (Stream inputStream = stream.AsStreamForRead())
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Anniversaries));
            tempAnniversaries = serializer.ReadObject(inputStream) as Anniversaries;
        }

        return tempAnniversaries;            
    }
```

and here is the Run method

```
public sealed class TileUpdater : IBackgroundTask
{        
    GeneralAnniversariesManager generalManager = new GeneralAnniversariesManager();
    Anniversaries tempAnn = new Anniversaries();        
    string test = "skata";

    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {  
        DateTime curentTime = new DateTime();         

     var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
     await generalManager.InitializeAnniversariesAsync().AsAsyncAction();
     curentTime = DateTime.Now;
     var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
     updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);

     updater.Clear();

     for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
          {
           var tile = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150BlockAndText01);
           tile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].InnerText = test + i;
           tile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[1].InnerText = curentTime.ToString();

           updater.Update(new TileNotification(tile));
          }

            defferal.Complete();
    }
```

Comment: Your first `using` statement is not enclosing the other part of the code.

Comment: How are you calling `Run`?

Comment: Run is being called from the background task

Comment: What do you mean is not enclosing, I use the same code in the main app and it works. Please forgive my ignorance, I' completely newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by deadlock you mean that the deserialization method finishes too late and your original program tries to read the data before it's finished loading.

It depends on how complicated/reliable you want your solution to be and how you're intending to use the program. The simplest way relies on the fact that the directory creation function is always 100% atomic in Windows/Unix and OSX. For example at the top of your readFile function have something like this.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("lock");
```

Before you start parsing the results of your async action in TileUpdater, have a loop that looks like this.

```
while (Directory.Exists("lock"))
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

This assumes that everything is happening in the same directory, generally you'll want to replace "lock" with a path that leads to the user's temp directory for their version of Windows/Linux/OSX.

If you want to implement something more complicated where you're reading from a series of files while at the same time reading the deserialized output into your class, you'll want to use something like a System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue that allows your threads to act completely independently without blocking each other.

Incidentally I'm assuming that you know that the class Process and the function .waitfor() exists. You can spin off a thread and then at a later point, halt the main thread until the spawned thread finishes.

Comment: This is not exactly the case. I want to populate a list with the contents of the xml file inside the background task and after some processing display the results on a live tile. The deadlock occurs when I call the readfile task. No ui is involved. As I said the same code works fine on the main program. I can send you a link of the project to test it if you want.

Comment: Sure, can you please send a link?

Comment: Sure. http://1drv.ms/1kpNEPd. Thank you very much again.I think the problem occurs in the AnniversaryManager class in the readFile method when I try to assign the serializer to an tempSnniversary object.

Comment: Don't thank me just yet, it doesn't open in my version of Visual Studio.

EDIT: Pressed enter too early. I meant to add that async/await don't actually make your program multithreaded and are known to cause these kinds of errors. That's why I suggested using CreateDirectory/ConcurrentQueue and the Process class if you actually want your stuff to be multithreaded. 

You're using them constantly, without stepping through your code I can't tell which one is causing it, but I suggest removing them and implementing another method to insure data coherency.

Comment: I have never used createDirectory etc before. Any chance for a very small example? The thanking is for your the time you spend, I apreciate it.

Comment: Try changing your readFile call into "this.Anniversaries = readFile(FileName);", without using async. Maybe I'm missing something but it looks like your instantiating Anniversaries in the class, but not actually assigning any data to it. You're writing to tempAnniversaries, and returning it from readFile, but not writing it to Anniversaries (the object) that you're returning from PopulateAnniversaries. I assumed it was a locking error but maybe this is the source of your problem. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I've found where the problem is. At the namespaces, I've tried a try and catch and I got an exception about using different namespaces at the datacontract serealizer. I have updated the code like this

```
            file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("EortologioMovingEntries.xml");
        try
        {
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream =
            await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            using (Stream inputStream = stream.AsStreamForRead())
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Anniversaries), "Anniversaries", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Eortologio.Model");
                tempAnniversaries = serializer.ReadObject(inputStream) as Anniversaries;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.ToString();
            tempAnniversaries.Entries.Add(new AnniversaryEntry("Ena", DateTime.Now, "skata", PriorityEnum.High));                
        }
```

I don't get any exceptions now but the tempAnniversaries returns null. Any ideas?